# anaconda prompt stuck - Activate.bat

Tags: anaconda, prompt

Very inexperienced user here so forgive my ignorance.

Having a problem after launching Anaconda Prompt. I just get a flashing cursor. The top of the window reads *'Anaconda Prompt - C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\Activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'*

I have tried reinstalling but it doesn't solve this issue - any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue whenever i open the anaconda prompt it closes automatically so i've had a solution.
-Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”
-Click the “Environment Variables…” button.
-add these paths under the path variables:
 C:..\Anaconda3 [Anaconda path]
 C:..\Anaconda3\Scripts
press "OK"

now in the Start search type cmd and write your conda commandes. cmd now is able to recognize your conda commands.I am using windows 10 .
I hoe this solution suits you well.